# Makefile not generating object code or executable

Tags: linux, object, makefile, terminal, executable

I'm trying to write a makefile that generates assembly code, object code, and an executable from a .c file.  This is the contents of my makefile:

```
good_echo.s: good_echo.c
    gcc -S -fstack-protector-all good_echo.c
good_echo.o: good_echo.s
    gcc -S good_echo.s -o good_echo.o
good_echo: good_echo.o
    gcc -v good_echo.o -o good_echo
clean:
    rm -f good_echo.o good_echo.s good_echo
```

When I enter make into terminal, it only generates the assembly code.  Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Can you show the actual make command you typed and the output you get (I mean like cut and paste the actual text not paraphrased)?

Comment: The command I type into terminal is literally "make".  The output I get is "gcc -S -fstack-protector-all good_echo.c". When I check the folder contents only the .s file is added

Comment: Aha, you've updated the makefile though; it's not the same as it was when you originally posted it.

Comment: Yes I did it before I saw your reply. My apologies

Answer (score 2):

If you check the GNU make manual [How make Processes a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html) you'll notice this sentence:

> make reads the makefile in the current directory and begins by processing the first rule.

Followed by in the next paragraph:

> If some other rule is not depended on by the goal (or anything it depends on, etc.), that rule is not processed, unless you tell make to do so (with a command such as make clean).

Here your first rule says to build `good_echo.s`, and none of the other targets are prerequistes of that, so it's the only one built.

If you run `make good_echo` then all will be built.  Alternatively you can ensure that the rule to build the target `good_echo` is the *first* rule in your makefile.

Or, you can use an often-used idiom and create a target `all` as the first rule which depends on the things you want to generate:

```
all: good_echo
```

To be clear, other than the first rule in the makefile it's not important in which order the rules are defined.

*ETA*

As pointed out by Joseph Quinsey in the comments, your rule here:

```
good_echo.o: good_echo.s
        gcc -S good_echo.s -o good_echo.o
```

is incorrect.  The `-S` option tells the compiler to stop after generating assembly and write it out, but already have assembly as your input.  You want an object file, so you should use the `-c` option to tell the compiler to stop after generating an object file (and not try to link):

```
good_echo.o: good_echo.s
        gcc -c good_echo.s -o good_echo.o
```

To be more clear: the compiler can infer what type of *input* it's given by using the extension to the file (in this case `.s` means assembly)--or you can force it with the `-x` option if you prefer--but it won't infer the type of *output* you want: you always have to tell it that with options such as `-c`, `-S`, and `-E`.  If you don't use any of those then it will run all steps and try to generate an executable program.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I really appreciate it.  I've gone and added the all: good echo to my program and I'm getting "gcc -S -fstack-protector-all good_echo.c /
gcc -S good_echo.s -o good_echo.o /
gcc -v good_echo.o -o good_echo /
gcc: good_echo.o: No such file or directory /
Using built-in specs. ......."

Comment: @chloapsoap: The gcc manual say `"-S ... do not assemble"`. So the command `gcc -S good_echo.s -o good_echo.o` looks odd to me (but I haven't tested it).